# Show selected value from mat-select multiple in ts file

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I am using  with multiple.I want to show the selected value in console. I am using Angular 6 Material design
I am getting the value in html. But i want to get all the selected value in comma separated in ts file.
Below is my code.

```
<form [formGroup]="searchUserForm" fxFlex fxLayout="column" autocomplete="off" style="margin: 30px">
    <mat-select placeholder="User Type" formControlName="userType" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let filters of userTypeFilters" [value]="filters.key" (click)="tosslePerOne(allSelected.viewValue)">
            {{filters.value}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option #allSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="0">All</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</form>

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatOption } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  searchUserForm: FormGroup;

  userTypeFilters = [
    {
      key: 1, value: 'Value 1',
    },
    {
      key: 2, value: 'Value 2',
    },
    {
      key: 3, value: 'Value 3',
    },
    {
      key: 4, value: 'Value 4',
    }
  ];
  @ViewChild('allSelected') private allSelected;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchUserForm = this.fb.group({
      userType: new FormControl('')
    });
  }
tosslePerOne(all){ 
   if (this.allSelected.selected) {  
    this.allSelected.deselect();
    return false;
}
  if(this.searchUserForm.controls.userType.value.length==this.userTypeFilters.length)
    this.allSelected.select();

}
  toggleAllSelection() {
    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      this.searchUserForm.controls.userType
        .patchValue([...this.userTypeFilters.map(item => item.key), 0]);
    } else {
      this.searchUserForm.controls.userType.patchValue([]);
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the value (which in the case of `multiple` will be an array) via `this.searchUserForm.get('userType').value`.

Based on what you bind as a `value` in your `mat-option`, you will get an array of different values/objects.

To get the complete object including `key` and `value`, bind it like this `[value]="filters"`. If you just want an array of one of the properties, add that property to the binding.

Comment: By using this i am getting index value in Array [1, 2, 3] like this. I want the values like Value 1,Value 2, Value 3 @Johar Zaman

Comment: See the edited answer. Based on what you bind in your `mat-option` you will get a different array of values.

Comment: Yes , its working. Thank you.I have one more question. I have a table in which one column is having data Value1, Value 2. So on select of Value1 from mat-select , only Value1 row should display.And if i will deselect value1 , then again all table data should display. Can you please help me how to do this. @Fabian kung

Comment: Have a look at the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering), it explains how to filter a table. Also there are plenty of resources on how to filter a table based on an input control. If you put in some work and are not able to achieve it, post the code in a new question.

Comment: The problem is I can not use mat-table. I have to use boostrap table.@Fabian Kung.

Comment: As I already mentioned, if you are facing an issue with this, have already tried various approaches and researched the problem, post another question. This is not the place to troubleshoot this issue, this question has been answered.

Comment: this.searchUserForm.get('userType').value this is not working "All" option, When i am selecting All i am not getting comma separated value @Fabian Kung. And i can not change this [value]="filters.key"  to [value]="filters.value" , if i am doing then on select of "Select All" , other options are not selecting